# particular solution of non-homogeneous linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm an engineering school sophomore. I have a question that is there any other ways to get a particular solution except variational of parameters.

specifically, I want to solve second order nonhomogeneous linear ODE like $$x^2 y''-3xy'+4y=x^2 \ln x.$$ I could get a homogeneous solution easily, but I have no idea about a particular solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2 y''-3xy'+4y=x^2 \ln x.$$
Substitute $x=e^t$:
$$y''(t)-4y'(y)+4y(t)=te^{2t} $$
Solve the homogeneous DE:
$$r^2-4r+4=(r-2)^2=0 \implies r=2$$
$$\implies y_h(t)=(c_1+c_2t)e^{2t}$$
Then your guess should be:
$$y_p=t^2(At+B)e^{2t}$$

---

You can also integrate directly:
$$y''(t)-4y'(y)+4y(t)=te^{2t} $$
$$(ye^{-2t})''=t$$
$$y(t)=\left(\dfrac {t^3}6+c_1t+c_2\right)e^{2t}$$
$$y(x)=\left(\dfrac {\ln^3 x}6+c_1\ln x+c_2\right)x^{2}$$

Comment: let me ask 1 question! what does r means in 3rd equation? I haven't thought about substitution... so your answer was so helpful to me.

Comment: It's the polynomial characteristic...Since the differential equation become a second order DE with constant coefficients. @katekim

Comment: I added more lines. Is it more clear now @katekim

Comment: oh yeah thank you very much!! actually I haven't learned about DE, not ODE, so there was some trouble to understand DE like y''-4y'y+4y=0. But now I understood and it was so helpful to me. thanks!!

Comment: You're very welcome. Your differential equation is Cuachy Euler equation you can check the wiki page for it. @katekim